# How do I inject registry with nLite before the setup finishes the installation?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-registry, nlite

I'm trying to inject a key into the Windows XP's registry using nLite. I want it injected before the second stage setup (before it enters the graphical setup). I tried using addons but I discovered that it injects after the installation is complete (right before it loads into the desktop). Is there any way to manipulate the setup files so I can inject that way my registry?

EDIT: This is the addon .inf file:

```
[General]
builddate=01/16/2022
descripton=Adds required registry for minlogon to work out of the box
language=English
title=Minlogon Registry Hack
version=1.0
website=
forcelang=English

[registry_addreg]
HKLM,"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon","Config",0x4,0x17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look deep in the I386 folder (in the root of the CD), you can find some .inf files with the prefix HIVE***.INF. Those are the hives that the so called "character-mode" setup installs before the graphical setup phase begins. The format is very simple, it uses the same syntax nLite uses for it's [registry_addreg] so you can copy and paste the lines you're intrested. But note the fact that the registry will be reconstructed from the ground up when the graphical setup registers devices so the lines you added will not take effect after the installation, use the addons in combination with this trick if you want that behaviour.